# Batch file that creates folder with wildcard in path

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, xcopy

I want to write a batch file that creates a folder (if it does not exist) and copies a certain file into that folder. So far so good.

The problem is that one folder in the path varies slightly from time to time, so a wildcard becomes necessary.

The following code works just fine but obviously misses to create the folder (Reports). So if the folder is not there, it simply does nothing.

```
for /r "c:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages" &&G in ("LocalState\acn\Reports") do @if exist %%G xcopy /s /i /y c:\temp\Reporting "%%G"
```

The full path is:
`c:\Users\FSchneider\AppData\Local\Packages\“WILDCARD"\LocalState\acn\Reports\`

Any idea?

Comment: Why `&&G in`? Should be `%%G in`.

Comment: Sorry. Typo. You're right!

Comment: So does it work now?

Comment: The piece I stated above does. But I need some code before that, which creates the folder 'Reports' (if it doesn't exist already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add `/d` switch in `for` to indicate you're looking for a directory, not a file
- Add `*` and omit quotes in the wildcard to indicate it's actually a wildcard
- No need for `if exist` now

  ```
  for /d /r "%LocalAppData%\Packages" %%G in (LocalState\acn.*) do xcopy /s /i /y c:\temp\Reporting "%%G\Reports"
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Somehow still doesn't work. Keeps giving me error messages that it's not possible to create the folder. Maybe it's easier to simply add a separate piece of code that only creates the folder?

Comment: The 'acn' folder always exists. In  fact all folders do except the one where the wildcard comes into play. Its name contains an always fixed name and a from time to time varying  number code.

Comment: Thanks! At least the folder is being created now. Unfortunately the content of 'c:\temp\Reporting' is not being copied.

Comment: Thanks mate! Works just fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Next script could help.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions

set "_fldrtop=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages"

set "_fldrsub=LocalState\acn"
if not "%~1"=="" set "_fldrsub=%~1"     :: my testing data, remove this line

set "_fldrlow=Reports"
if not "%~2"=="" set "_fldrlow=%~2"     :: my testing data, remove this line

for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /AD "%_fldrtop%"') do (
  if exist "%_fldrtop%\%%G\%_fldrsub%\" (
    if exist "%_fldrtop%\%%G\%_fldrsub%\%_fldrlow%\" (
      echo echo "%_fldrtop%\%%G\%_fldrsub%\%_fldrlow%\"
    ) else (
      echo md "%_fldrtop%\%%G\%_fldrsub%\%_fldrlow%\"
    )
    rem echo xcopy /s /i /y c:\temp\Reporting "%_fldrtop%\%%G\%_fldrsub%\%_fldrlow%\"
  )
)
```

**Output**:

```
==>D:\bat\SO\31672436.bat

==>D:\bat\SO\31672436.bat "LocalState\Cache"
md "C:\Users\UName\AppData\Local\Packages\winstore_cw5\LocalState\Cache\Reports\"

==>D:\bat\SO\31672436.bat "LocalState\Cache" 2
echo "C:\Users\UName\AppData\Local\Packages\winstore_cw5\LocalState\Cache\2\"
```