# Search file with wildcard path

Tags: batch-file, path

I want to write a script to prompt user for file path and list all files found. The file path can contain wildcards. Something similar to [this](https://superuser.com/a/524455). But the batch script version of it. For example:

```
C:\Somewhere\user*\app\version-*.*\start.exe
```

The files might be located like this:

```
C:\Somewhere\user345\app\version-1.0\start.exe
C:\Somewhere\user898\app\version-1.2\start.exe
C:\Somewhere\user898\app\version-1.3\start.exe
```

I tried to use `FOR` and it turns out to be so much harder than expected because `FOR` does not support wildcards in the middle of a path.
Is there a way to list these files? (Maybe without using `for`?)

Comment: You may wish to make your provided example more specific. You are talking of listing all files found, but I can tell you without seeing your computer that they will all be called start.exe. Are the paths etc. you have provided correct or have you just made them up for the purposes of an answer with the hope of changing them later on your own?

Comment: Which part of example @Compo? yes, I made them up

Comment: Related: [Batch file that creates folder with wildcard in path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31672436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this recursive solution works pretty well; you may name it **WCDIR.bat**:

```
@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1" neq "" set "next=%~1" & goto next
echo Show files selected by several wild-cards
echo/
echo WCDIR wildcardPath
echo/
echo Each folder in the path may contain wild-cards
echo the last part must be a file wild-card
goto :EOF

:next
for /F "tokens=1* delims=\" %%a in ("%next%") do set "this=%%a" & set "next=%%b"
if defined next (
   for /D %%a in ("%this::=:\%") do (
      setlocal
      cd /D "%%~a" 2>NUL
      if not errorlevel 1 call :next
      endlocal
   )
) else (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A:-D "%this%" 2^>NUL') do echo %%~Fa
)
exit /B
```

**EDIT**: I fixed a small bug in the last `for /F` command.

For example, the output of `WCDIR.bat C:\Windows\Sys*\find*.exe` command in my Windows 8.1 64-bits computer is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\find.exe
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\findstr.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the command [***`Where /?`***](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html)

The **`WHERE`** command is roughly equivalent to the UNIX 'which' command. By default, the search is done in the current directory and in the PATH.

```
    @echo off
    Where /R "%programfiles%" *winrar.exe
    pause
```

---

```
@echo off
:: Example d'input
set UserInput=*drive*

:: building the Pattern
set cmd=%Userinput%.exe

:: storage Where.exe command in a macro, the execution will be faster
set whereCmd=where.exe /r c:\windows\ %cmd%

:: execution of macro and output formatting
for /f %%a in ('%whereCmd%') do echo %%~nxa --^> %%a
pause
```

Comment: This not works. The path given in /R switch can NOT contain wild-cards.

Comment: I tried `where /R C:\Windows\Sys* find*.exe` and got something like "ERROR: invalid directory". Windows 8.1 here. Works this command for you?

Comment: @Aacini `where /R "C:\Windows\System32" *find*.exe` this works and this too `where /R "C:\Windows\System32" *f*d*.exe`

Comment: Excuse me? This topic is about _"Search file with **wildcard path**"_, that is, the problem here is that _"`FOR` does not support wildcards **in the middle of a path**"_ (as the question description specify). A solution should find files with a path like this one: `C:\Windows\Sys*\find.exe`...

Comment: ... (like the first example in this question: `C:\Somewhere\user*\app\version-*.*\start.exe`)