# Work around Linux wildcards with Batch

Tags: linux, windows, bash, batch-file, cp

I am basically trying to implement this line in Windows Batch : `cp */win/lib/*.dll ./bin`. Linux is kind enough to let me have these fancy wildcards working, but Windows won't take any of it. What's the best way to make that work ? A `for` loop seems a bit overkill, but neither of `copy, xcopy, robocopy` seems to implement that kind of fancy work.

Thanks by advance !

EDIT : for context, I'm writing a Makefile for mingw32-make, and I want to copy a bunch of dependencies to the executable's folder.

Comment: You can't really compare `batch` to `bash`. Maybe you want to take a look into PowerShell instead, a somewhat reasonable shell based on MS-Windows.

Comment: Far from comparing them, I'm trying to find a set of commands that has the same effect as the one I gave. I'm sticking with Batch because that's what mingw32 uses (well for instance mingw32-w64), so PowerShell isn't really an option.

Comment: Oh well. For the record, this line works in PowerShell. Now I wish mingw32-make could use PowerShell.

Comment: This same question (with a different title) was made before at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599099/search-file-with-wildcard-path/) and already have an accepted answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `FOR` loop may feel like overkill, but we're talking about batch here, so why not simply be happy that there is a way to do what you want *at all*... `:)` I know of no other possibility to do this (apart from using external tools). Note that backslashes in the directory mask need to be doubled for regex use in `FINDSTR`, which is done in line 4. The caret `^` for the negating character class needs to be escaped twice since it is interpreted twice.

**Edit:** Correction to not include `.dll`s in subdirectories of `*\win\lib`.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET dirmask=\win\lib
SET extension=.dll
SET regex=%dirmask:\=\\%\\[^^^^\\]*\%extension%$
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /S /B ^| FINDSTR /R "%regex%"') DO COPY %%G .\bin
```

Comment: Wow haha, thanks a lot for that. I definitely wouldn't have been able to come up with it alone. Now I'm seriously considering ditching MinGW and going for Cygwin :P seems like my Makefile would only be grateful.