# Check if file exists within certain path without restriction to subfolder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch checking for a specific file like this:

```
if exist "C:\Program Files\App\App version number\file.exe" (
    echo EXISTS
) else (
   echo NOT EXIST!
)
```

I want to be able to check for the `file.exe` in any version so it might be in:

```
"C:\Program Files\App\App v.1\file.exe"
"C:\Program Files\App\App v.2\file.exe"
```

How can I skip the version number as a requirement inside the path?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599099/search-file-with-wildcard-path/39600909#39600909)

Comment: `where /R "C:\Program Files\App" "file.exe"`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using the `WHERE` command with conditional operators.

```
where /Q /R "C:\Program Files\App" file.exe && echo found || echo not found
```

Comment: This is by far the cleanest way I think. I did not know about that command. Would you mind if I add some explanation to that?

Comment: This will only work if you actually want to search in *all* subdirectories of App. It will not work if you want to search in `...\App\App v.1` and `...\App\App v.2` (as the OP stated) but not in `...\App\NotHere\*`.

Comment: extending it a bit when you want to work with an IF-construction

```WHERE /Q /R "C:\Program Files\App" file.exe && SET FOUND=OK || FOUND=NOT OK```
and then you can get the result with
```ECHO %FOUND%```

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal
set AppDir=
for /d %%d in ("C:\Program Files\App\App v*") do if exist "%%d\file.exe" set "AppDir=%%d"
if defined AppDir (
    echo EXISTS - it's in "%AppDir%"
) else (
    echo NOT EXIST!
)
endlocal
```

(Update: Edited to put quotes around variables in case there's a filename that contains a special character such as `&`. Thanks to @aschipfl for pointing this out. On the other hand, there's no need to use `%%~d` instead of just `%%d` because `%%d` won't have any quotes anyway.)

Comment: Better quote handling: `if exist "%%~d\file.exe" set "AppDir=%%~d"` and `echo EXISTS - it's in "%AppDir%"`...

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit overkill but should work.

main.bat:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('sub.bat') do (
    if "x%%i"=="x" (
        echo "Not found!"
    ) ELSE (
        echo "Found in %%i"
    )
)
```

sub.bat:

```
@echo off
set your_path="C:\Your Path\"
cd /d %your_path%
for /r %%p in (file.exe) do echo %%p
```

Explanation:

The main batch is the one to execute. It reads the output of the sub batch and reacts properly.

Set the root for the search to the variable `your_path`. It will change the directory and then searches with an `/R`ecursive loop through the current directory and looks for the file you set in the parenthesis. If the file is found, it will `echo` that to get read by the main file.

Feel free to ask further questions :)