# Batch, use wildcard in set

Tags: batch-file, set, wildcard

I want to put a batch file to modify a line in a file in a GPO.

The problem I have is the path is different for each user.

So, I tried to use a wildcard in my path but it doesnt work.

This bat is working:

```
@echo off &setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "search=test"
set "replace=test2"
set "textfile=%appdata%\Thunderbird\Profiles\5xu9scdm.default\prefs.js"
set "newfile=%appdata%\Thunderbird\Profiles\5xu9scdm.default\prefs2.js"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
  set "line=%%i"
  set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
  echo(!line!
))>"%newfile%"
del %textfile%
rename %newfile% prefs.js
endlocal
```

But if I use a wildcard in the set, it doesnt work anymore.

```
@echo off &setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "search=test"
set "replace=test2"
set "textfile=%appdata%\Thunderbird\Profiles\*.default\prefs.js"
set "newfile=%appdata%\Thunderbird\Profiles\*.default\prefs2.js"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
  set "line=%%i"
  set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
  echo(!line!
))>"%newfile%"
del %textfile%
rename %newfile% prefs.js
endlocal
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Wildcards can only be used in the last element in a path.

Comment: And `for /F` is not capable of resolving, so you need to wrap around a `for /D` loop to do that...

Comment: See: [Search file with wildcard path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599099/search-file-with-wildcard-path/39600909#39600909)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach does not work, because wild-cards can only occur in the last element of a path. In addition, `for /F` is not capable of handling wild-cards. So you need to wrap around a `for /D` loop to resolve the wild-cards, like this (supposing there is only a single matching directory `*.default`):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "search=test"
set "replace=test2"
set "rootdir=%appdata%\Thunderbird\Profiles\*.default"
set "textfile=prefs.js"
set "newfile=prefs2.js"

for /D %%j in ("%rootdir%") do (
    > "%%~j\%newfile%" (
        for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%%~j\%textfile%") do (
            set "line=%%i"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
            echo(!line!
            endlocal
        )
    )
    > nul move /Y "%%~j\%newfile%" "%%~j\%textfile%"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

What I changed besides inserting the `for /D` loop:

- delayed expansion is toggled within the loop, so exclamation marks in the text files are not lost;
- all paths are properly quoted; to use a quoted file path in `for /F`, `usebackq` is required;
- the replacement of the original file by the modified one is done by a single `move` command rather than `del` plus `rename`;